# Maven dependency without version in filename

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a Maven Java project and am trying to include a dependency that does not have the version as part of the filename.  The dependency had this in its pom file to create a file name without the version:

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
```

The dependency jar is in com/example/foobar/1.0.0/foobar.jar

I have the dependency in my pom file set as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Whenever I try to build, Maven appends the version to the filename it is looking for and cannot find it giving me the following messages:

Downloading from maven-repos: com/example/foobar/1.0.0/foobar-1.0.0.jar

Could not resolve dependencies

What can I do to get this dependency?

Comment: Can you share the link to that library in the repository?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `finalName` doesn't not have any effect on the artifact filename in a repository. Or does it?

Comment: Also, are you sure you've added all repositories you're going to use, and at least one of them contain the artifact you're going to use (+ with proper directory layout, files naming, etc)?

Comment: @fluffy, yes the correct repository is being used.  The message from my Maven build shows it looking in the correct repository and the correct directory.  The problem is that is looks for the wrong filename of the jar since it adds the version to the filename.

Comment: @RetoHöhener, the actual repository is a private corporate repository.  What I've given is an example which illustrates my problem.

Comment: Is it deployed correctly to the repository? E.g. can you find it using the web interface of your repository?

Comment: @jnorman I mean that as far as I understand how Maven works, `build.finalName` can be anything, it only stands for the name of artifacts built in the target directory (and then i.e. deployed to an FTP/whatever, but not a Maven repository), but the artifact and its supplemental data are always deployed at the very specific path in the repository regardless the value in `build.finalName`.

Comment: @jnorman What do you get when trying to browse your private repository in your web- browser? Does it contain the group path directories `com/example/foobar/1.0.0/`? Which files the directory contains if the artifact directory really exists? Is it possible that someone simply copied the artifact to that location by a script violating the Maven conventions, not using `mvn deploy`?

Comment: @fluffy, yes I can navigate to com/example/foobar/1.0.0 and it contains two files:  foobar.jar and foobar.pom.  These were put there by an automated process.

Comment: @jnorman Interesting. I've just found an extra option for adding a repository, called `layout`. I've never heard of it before. What if you try to switch it to `legacy` as mentioned to https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories ?

Comment: The `<finalName> ..</finalName>` is only to change the name in `target/` directory nothing else. Very useful in relationship with creating docker images.

Comment: @fluffy, from your link, I see "In order to be a Maven repository artifact, a POM file must live within the structure $BASE_REPO/groupId/artifactId/version/artifactId-version.pom".  This makes me think the repository has to have the version as part of the filename, so I will get with somebody who controls that to see if it can be changed.  Thank you.